# Как нарисовать линию и превратить её в массив точек Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте мне нужно нарисовать линию мышкой и сделать так, что бы объект шёл по неё. Я понимаю, что нужно её нарисовать и превратить в массив точек но я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Вопрос слишком абстрактный. Например, для рисования прямой линии  подойдёт алгоритм Брезенхема или другой для растеризации

Comment: В `Unity` есть `LineRenderer`, всевозможный рейкастинг и все необходимое. Он просто языка не знает, пишет `RigidBody2D` вместо `Rigidbody2D`  и не понимает в чем ошибка, `IntelliSense` тут бессилен.